# Python Memoization and File Content Hashing

Tags: python, file, memoization, persistent-storage

I'm looking for a Python memoizer, preferrably like [@functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), but with the extension that every input parameter (of the hashed function) that is of type Python standard file handle (`_io.TextIOWrapper`) should be opened (if not already opened) and its content should be read, hashed and included in the hash-chain used to calculate the memoization-key of the function evaluation.